# pass string to main method in another class

Tags: java

I'm creating a project that need to pass string from first program to second program but i need to pass string in main method of first class. I've googled but i cannot find what i need, mostly people use setter and getter to pass string between class but i cannot do that in main method.

How to pass string in main method of another class?

what i need is shown here:

```
public class FirstProgram{
    public void first(){
        String a = "hello";
    }
}

public class SecondProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //i need to pass string here
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass from where to where?

Comment: This is not the way you should be using Java.

Comment: You can simply call `SecondProgram.main(new String[] {a})` from your `first` method in class `FirstProgram`, assuming both classes are in the classpath. But is that what you want? Question is somewhat unclear ...

Comment: Note that you'd use the main method as an _entry point_, i.e. a way to start the program and pass parameters from the outside (e.g. the command line). Inside the program you just create instances of classes and call methods on them as normal (this should be what you need to learn if you haven't yet) - but those "internally" called methods should never be named "main" to avoid confusion.

Comment: You don't have two programs (applications) I assume but rather two classes in one application so there is no need to call the main() method internally. I suggest you delete this question and create a new one where you describe what you're trying to do and why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

First.java:

```
public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Second.main(args);
    }
}
```

Second.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Second {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(args).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If you execute `java First foo bar baz bat` on the command line, you'll see that `Second` prints out "foo bar baz bat" in the console.

I don't recommend it.

You have to start your app by calling `main` in some program.  Your `First` can invoke `main` in `Second` as shown, but it's `First` that starts the process.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good approach to take, but technically you can call the main method of the Second program and pass whatever argument you like

```
    public class FirstProgram{
        public void first(){
            String a = "hello";
            SecondProgram.main(new String []{a});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty confusing question. 
But you can do smth like that:

```
public class FirstProgram{
    public String first(){
        String a = "hello";
        return a;
    }
}

public class SecondProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FirstProgram firstProgram = new FirstProgram();
        String result = firstProgram.first();
    }
}
```

Comment: you seem to be mistaken between cause and consequence. the FirstProgram should call the SecondProgram, not vice versa